# How to calculate rolling up values in python

Tags: python

I have a python dict with the following values

```
    d = {
    "k1": [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]],
    "k2": [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]],
    "k3": [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
    "k4": [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

}
```

I need to apply a reduce/roll up function on this.

For k1, I am expecting the value as ((1,0,0)+(0,1,1)+(0,0,1)+(0,1,0)+ (0,0,1)+ (1,0,0) -> 1+1+1+1+1+1 =6) and so on), k2 as 4 and for k3, it is 7.

For e.g. for k1, I can calculate using this

```
k1_sum = sum([x | y | z  for x,y,z in zip([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])])

k2_sum = sum([x | y  for x,y in zip([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])])
```

How do I dynamically unpack the values. There could be several values for each key. It is not fixed. There can be numerous keys.

I would like to write a function and by passing each key, I would like to get the rolled up value.

Comment: try `k1_sum = sum([x | y | z for x,y,z in zip(*d["k1"])])`

Comment: I can have 2 or more lists inside each value. How can I dynamically declare variables x,y,z or more based on the number of lists inside

Comment: Is this a homework assignment of sorts, where you're not allowed to use libraries? Or would using something like `functools.reduce` be an idea?

Comment: It is not a homework assignment.

Comment: ah, i see, since you are or'ing each value, `[ft.reduce(lambda x,y:x|y, v)for v in zip(*d["k1"]
)]` should work, but be sure to `import functools as ft`

Comment: I posted an answer below, but I don't see why you would say it's 5 for k3 - looks like another 7 to me?

Comment: You are right. Let me correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`functools.reduce` is perfect for the job:

```
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce

d = {
    "k1": [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]],
    "k2": [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]],
    "k3": [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
    "k4": [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
}

sums = {key: sum(reduce(or_, t) for t in zip(*xss)) for key, xss in d.items()}

print(sums)
```

Result:

```
{'k1': 6, 'k2': 4, 'k3': 7, 'k4': 7}
```

Don't use heavier libraries than you need to (like numpy), unless you're using them anyway or you find they give you a performance advantage you need.

Comment: Why not just throw `map` and `functools.partial` into the mix if you're going this route. `{key: sum(map(partial(reduce, or_), zip(*xss))) for key, xss in d.items()}`

Comment: A solution with `map` and `partial` performs better, although I feel it suffers a bit in readability. It's definitely the better choice in some cases though.